# Prove or give a counterexample: If $||Te_j|| = ||T^*ej||$, then $T$ is normal

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a hard time with the following problem, which was taken from Axler's book (section A in chapter 7).

[image]

The following theorems may be useful:

[image]
[image]

$V$ is assumed to be a finite-dimensional inner product space (over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$).

I think the statement is false, but I can't come up with a counterexample.
Suppose $T$ is an operator on $V$ such that $||Te_j|| = ||T^*ej||$ for each $j$ and an orthonormal basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$.
Then

$$
\begin{align*}
0 &= ||Te_j||^2 - ||T^*e_j||^2\\
&= \langle Te_j, Te_j \rangle - \langle T^*e_j, T^*e_j \rangle\\
&= \langle T^*Te_j, e_j \rangle - \langle TT^*e_j, e_j \rangle\\
&= \langle (T^*T - TT^*)e_j, e_j \rangle.
\end{align*}
$$

So for any $v \in V$ (with $v = a_1 e_1 + \dots + a_n e_n$), we don't know if $\langle (T^*T - TT^*)v, v \rangle$ equals $0$ (to be able to use the first theorem, since $T^*T - TT^*$ if self-adjoint), because we only know that few terms become $0$ when we expand the product.
In other words, we don't know if $\langle (T^*T - TT^*)e_j, e_k \rangle = 0$ when $j \neq k$.

Comment: I think $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ should provide a counterexample.

Comment: The standard basis.  The point being that it *does* satisfy the condition as you noticed, but it's not normal.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I see, that will do, thanks.

Comment: (On the other hand, if there exists an orthonormal basis such that $\langle T e_i, T e_j \rangle = \langle T^* e_i, T^* e_j \rangle$ for each pair $i,j$, I think that should be sufficient to imply $T$ is normal.)